# How to alt+tab between more than 2 windows in GNOME 3?

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, 14.04

I have recently upgraded Ubuntu from 13.04 to 14.04. Soon I have noticed that the most commonly used short cut, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, had changed its meaning. It switches now only between the current and the previous application. Pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> more times does not have any effect.

I have discovered that <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> behaves like old <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. I tried to change short cuts, but all changes seem to be completely ignored(!).

How can I repair <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to work as previously?

Answer (score 1):

Just install the AlternateTab extension by gcampax: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/15/alternatetab/

(This took me about 10 seconds of Googling, I don't even use Gnome 3)

Comment: According to the page, AlternateTab resolves a different problem - grouping windows by application. I asked about switching between more than two applications.

Comment: I have found another solution, but apparently AlternateTab corrects this behavior, too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Changing shortcuts works fine, but a restart  or re-login may be necessary. This is why I didn't notice any change for the first time.

Detailed steps for anyone with the same problem. (Names of the options may differ, I'm translating from the Polish language version).

1. Click on the "power" button on the upper right corner of the screen.
2. Click on the settings button.
3. List item.
4. Choose "keyboard", then "shortcuts".
5. Choose "navigation", then "switch windows" (the one which has Super + Tab by default). Press Alt+Tab. If a warning dialog window appears, then accept the change.
6. If the change has no effect, restart the computer.

Comment: You shouldn't have to restart your computer technically, it should be enough to do something like ctrl+alt+f6 (to get a non-graphical prompt), then run something like `sudo service gnome3something stop` and then start it back up. For XFCE this service is called `lightdm` and this helps when you have issues when coming back from suspending your system etc. In summary: You only need to restart Gnome probably, not the entire system.